# Object reference error while creating Unity plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a simple Unity plugin.

I created a C# class and in the update I am calling

```
 AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"); 
     AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
```

When I debug the code in Mono, then jc shows "Object reference not set to instance of an object".
And then the following error is generated

```
JNI: Unable to find field id for 'currentActivity' (static)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Can anybody help me in this?

Comment: Problem is in your `AndrodJavaClass` constructor, not in your code in question

Comment: When does this message come up? In the constructor or when accessing `jc`?

Comment: @habib: what is the problem here?, I am following http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html Example 2.